# DropDownList always returns first item in Iron Speed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dropdownlistfor, ironspeed

I am using a DropDownlist in Iron Speed. My problem is that it always returns the first item in the selection, even though I use page.ispostback. This is my code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub PopulatePaidbyCompPeriodDropDownList(
        _ByVal selectedValue As String,
        _ByVal maxItems As Integer)
    Me.PaidbyCompPeriod.Items.Clear()
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings("Database").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select  distinct PeriodNumber,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), perioddateto, 23) AS payrolldate,
                YEAR(payrolldate) as yeardate from Payroll order by payrolldate
                desc", conn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            PaidbyCompPeriod.Items.Add(New ListItem(MonthName(Month(CDate(
                    reader.GetString(1)))) & " " & Day(CDate(reader.GetString(1)))
                    & ", " & Year(CDate(reader.GetString(1))), reader.GetInt32(0)
                    .ToString))
            DropDownList.Items.Add(New ListItem(reader.GetString(0).ToString,
                    reader.GetString(1).ToString))
        End While
        reader.Close()
        conn.Close()
        PaidByCompDate.Text = CDate(PaidbyCompPeriod.SelectedItem.Text)
                .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What version of iron speed are you using?

Comment: I am using version 9.2

Comment: Is the code you provided your own code or is it the iron speed generated code? Did you do the dropdown through iron speed's layout editor where you edit it in the formulas tab?

Comment: it's from iron speed populate dropdown and afterwards I changed it